# Is merging multiple XML files into one more efficient?

Tags: android, xml, string, file

So, I have a lot of strings (I reckon more than 100, easily.)...

I have 6-7 XML files across which these strings are spread out.

Now during development, it was obviously easier to put some similar strings into one file for convenience.
But now that I'm going to put my app on the market, I want it to be as efficient and fast as possible, even if by mere milliseconds.

Here's what I did :
I just made a copy of my project, exactly same , except I just made another XML file, copy-pasted all of the other files strings , and deleted all the other files.
Now I got 1 XML file.

Problem is My development device is new, and has 1GHz CPU...So I didn't really notice a difference, I want to know whether having just one XML file would be better for low end (and also high end) devices...

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this falls into the category of problem where readability would be more important than performance.  The performance difference between reading 6-7 files or just 1 would be barely anything, definitely nothing noticeable to the user.

I'd go with whichever makes your code cleanest as the readability will be worth more in the long run than saving 1 nanosecond of performance if it means losing hours of dev when you revisit it an it's just a mess of xml.